# How to theme a view block

Tags: views, blocks

I'm a drupal beginner. I'm using drupal 7 and views. I created a block using views in order to list my latest projects. I'm displaying the block in my home page. I would like to know how to override HTML and Css in order to display something like this: [image]

I want to use this code:

```
<div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                            <img src="assets/custom/img/project1.jpg" class="projectImg" title="project one">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Projects One</a></h4>
                            <p>
                                On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire
                            </p>
                            <a class="pull-right" href="#">more details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the view which you've created, expand Advanced Option column
2. open Theme:Information
3. copy the last theme suggestion from `Row style output` row
4. go ahead to the theme(project theme) folder and create that file,
   example, `views-view-fields--docs---page-1.tpl.php` (this is how my
   template looks like, this is just for an example), rescan the templates, and save the view.
5. debug `$fields` array (better install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, it provides useful functions, like `dpm()`, `dsm()`..)
6. Copy the code from the sample template and put into this template.
7. Lastly, put the output of fields (e.g. something like this `<?php print $fields['SOME_FIELD']->content; ?>`) to the desired html blocks..

Don't forget to clear the cache;

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented by @xurshid29 is good.

For me i use view modes, with that you can design the list as you want with a tpl file that you create and associate it with your view, you can also make more than one design for the same block.

This is a helpful link to see more details about this solution : [3 Easy Ways to Create View Modes in Drupal 7](http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/3-easy-ways-create-view-modes-drupal-7)